# Storekit / In App Purchases: Does the "Environment: Sandbox" tag disappear when I submit my app to the app store?

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase, storekit

This is my first time implementing In App Purchases. During development and testing of my In App Purchases, I see the following alerts during the purchase process:

[image]
[image]
[image]

My In App Purchases work perfectly and the app is close to submission.

Do I have to do something before I submit the app (to make the "Environment: Sandbox" tag go away) or is all of that handled automatically as I submit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to do nothing. This is just indication that you are using sandbox when your app will be submitted for production, reviewed and approved, this notification will not be shown to the users.