# InAppPurchase - Find mode (is Sandbox)

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

As you know, in InAppPurchase's development process we make purchase in sandbox environment
Is there a way to know if the purchase made on sandbox environment?

10x

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the sandbox mode the IAP dialog will have **[Environment: Sandbox]** above the OK button

Check this out for a screenshot:
[Storekit / In App Purchases: Does the "Environment: Sandbox" tag disappear when I submit my app to the app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719689/storekit-in-app-purchases-does-the-environment-sandbox-tag-disappear-when)

Comment: Buy how may i know while runtime if the purchase made in sandbox environment or not?

Comment: Is it possible to detect this in the code when a purchase is completed?

Comment: The usual IAP processes such as detect if purchased work exactly the same in Sandbox environment. No changes to your code should be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to work it out for good reason, because your code is expected to work for both modes seamlessly.